# Quill toolbar butons doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, editor, quill

I'm using quill editor in Laravel. There is a problem with toolbar. When i click on toolbar's button it doesn't respond. This is my code:

```
<div id="editor-container">  </div>
```

```
<script>

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', { theme: 'snow'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to Vue and Quill compatibility.

By default, Laravel will load Vue and mount to `#app` element. The `#app` element is the root element of your app. So when you load Quill, it doesn't works.

In order to make it work, you can either:

- Use [vue-quill-editor](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor).
- Mount to other element in your view, instead of `#app`
- Don't use Vue or don't load Vue in your view.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```html
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Brandon, it work in another services. But only in my site it doesn't work

Comment: Please explain your answer, instead of just putting some code. This helps the readers and increases your answer's credibility.